# IronPython fails to import on Linux Mint, but not on Windows

Tags: ironpython, linux-mint

I'm trying to import some .py files into another .py file. It's pretty simple, but I'm getting an error about it being unable to import anything.

Here's my error:

`IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException: No module named Abilities.Abstracts.AbstractAbility`

`at Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.LightExceptions.CheckAndThrow (System.Object value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0`

`at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.FuncCallInstruction2[System.Object,System.Object].Run (Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.InterpretedFrame frame) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run (Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.InterpretedFrame frame) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0`

And here's the offending code: 
`from Abilities.Abstracts.AbstractAbility import AbstractAbility`